# Is there any cli command for kubelet to know eviction policy/criteria for node?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet

I am getting a taint on one node about disk-pressure. I would like to check current eviction criteria for that node.

Do we have kubelet command to know current eviction policy/criteria?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check the eviction policy info unless hard eviction thresholds are defined and set in kubelet.

you can describe the node ( kubectl describe no ) to know the reason as why the pods are not getting scheduled on that node

Answer (score 0):

We can check the default criteria by looking at the `kubelet` flags.

`kubelet --help | grep eviction`

These values can be modified by adding below line in the config file.

`--eviction-hard="memory.available<200Mi,nodefs.available<500Mi,imagefs.available<1Gi" \`

source :- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#without-imagefs-1